# How to interact with different microservices in a cloud

Tags: java, rest, web-services, amazon-web-services, microservices

I am asking me every day how is it possible to communicate between 2 or more microservices. I have to know the other service to invoke the url with the correct parameter is that right? But if I deploy my services on aws at Amazon where do my services know which Ip addresses assigned to the other services?

For instance:

I uploaded and deployed service A and service B. Service B want to communicate with service A but service B doesn't know the exact IP of service A. Do I need to declare it somewhere in a config file or undertake aws(Amazon) this task for me?

My second question is about the authorization of each service. Every service need to create a token which is able to make a request. Is there a library outside where somebody can refer to? Or do I need to implement?

Many thanks

I know a lot of questions but hopefully someone can help me and solve this problems easly.

If someone have a good practical example of this, please share it.

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Comment: Sorry @Kayaman. I can`t be accurate. I just want to have some information and now I get it and that was my goal for this thread. Maybe some other people got this too and they got answered as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a services orchestration tool for SOA architecture. E.g. [ZooKeeper](http://highscalability.com/zookeeper-reliable-scalable-distributed-coordination-system) but there are another solutions and you can choose what is better for you.
2. A common approach is to use SSO (single signon) solution. And again there are some tools and protocols e.g. [Spring oauth](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/)

In simple words you logged in and get a toke which is used for each call of your services.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Now I can start my journey to the Spring framework:) Do you think its a good approach if i am starting with Spring Boot (Make services with the microservices pattern). After that, i start with docker and then deploy it on a cloud?